# Is it possible to mimic behaviour of `"$@"` in unix shell with a regular variable?

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh

copy=$@

for i in $copy
do
  echo $i
done
```

Will not do what

```
for i in "$@"
do
  echo $i
done
```

does. `copy="$@"` does not do the trick either, nor `for i in "$copy"`

I could use arrays but arrays are bashism and not posix conform.

**Is it possible to mimic behaviour of quoted `"$@"` with a regular variable?** How if so?

Comment: In bash, these are arrays, in POSIX sh, arrays don't exist. There might be some tricks for this though

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can use arrays:

```
copy=("$@")
for i in "${copy[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

In posix shell you can store properly quoted variable:

```
copy=$(printf "%q " "$@")
```

But then you need to somehow re-evaluate the expression. You can use [the unsafe eval](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048):

```
eval set -- "$copy";
for i in "$@"; do
     echo "$i"
done
```

Or, hmmm..., you can do some helper functions that will help with extraction of the values from the copy and the numbers of values in the copy and then iterate over them using the helper function. Like this:

```
get() { local pos=$2; eval set -- "$1"; eval printf %s \"\$$pos\"; };
no() { eval set -- "$1"; echo $#; }

for idx in $(seq $(no "$copy")); do
    i=$(get "$copy" "$idx")
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the printf approach fails in dash so either dash or the command is not posix. To assign the arguments to positional parameters via `set -- "foo" "bar baz"` is the only way I could think of.

Comment: How does it fail? Can you be more specific?

Comment: `dash: 1: printf: %q: invalid directive` (Works in bash)

Comment: Right, right, right, %q is not in posix. I guess then you would have to escape the string yourself. You may have /bin/printf installed from GNU coreutils, try to pick it up rather then the builtin. `command printf "%q " "$@"`